# Why is msg header not generated

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build my package (Gui), which contains a msg-folder, containing rect.msg, containing four Int32 values. In my CMakeLists.txt I added

```
rosbuild_genmsg()
```

When running cmake, the folder msg_gen is generated, containing the "generated"-file (containing "yes"). In my cpp-file (which location is {Gui}/foo/bar.cpp) I could use

```
#include "Gui/rect.h"
```

and it would build just fine. I committed it to my build server, and there it failed to build, giving the error *Gui/rect.h: No such file or directory*. . And for some reason, since then, my local rosmake couldn't find the header any more either.

I've searched and found nothing about what is causing this. I tried several things that didn't work, including:

```
rosbuild_add_generated_msgs(rect.msg)
```

This would tell the compiler that the messages are generated during the build. I also tried including "ros/ros.h" above including the message-header.

I checked my manifest.xml but that doesn't seem to be relavant for this.

I'm sure it's a rooky mistake, I've been working with ros (and cmake) little over a month, running into several issues that would eventually become clear to me, but this one doesn't.

TIA

Jan Willem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11097/why-is-msg-header-not-generated/) by [JWvanSilfhout](https://answers.ros.org/users/1029/jwvansilfhout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-01**:
Does a simple make clean && make fix that? Otherwise try cleaning up the cmake file if you added a lot of test stuff in there - rosbuild_genmsg() should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eventually I solved it. It appears that the contents of my message were not valid: I used the type Int32 instead of int32. This became clear to me when I removed all references to the non-existent header, built it and looked very closely at the build output in QtCreator.

Because of the wrong type used, it gave a very non-descriptive error, telling me that Gui/msg/Int32.msg was not found (the message name was Gui/msg/rect.msg).

---

Originally posted by [JWvanSilfhout](https://answers.ros.org/users/1029/jwvansilfhout/) with karma: 26 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0